# JMeter proxy Setting

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter Recording,getting error The proxy server is refusing connections.I want to know as for the multiple users login in Jmeter  I am using CSV data config,we will specify the parameters in csv file,what about the button in log in page.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What is the error?  Not sure I understand the rest of your question

Answer (score 2):

With All given answers if your problem not solved then try these two with following previous answers:

1- Try to configure with different ports Ex.. 8080, 8888, 9090

2- Check if you accidentally typing in HTTPS instead of HTTP while recording.

Answer (score 0):

1. For JMeter proxy configuration:

   - Check out [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide (for general information and idea)
   - In JMeter:

     - File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create
     - WorkBench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder -> Start
   - In browser network configuration:

     - Proxy host: localhost
     - Proxy port: 8888
     - Use proxy for all protocols: check
     - No proxy for: remove everything (or at least localhost, 127.0.0.1 and ::1
2. For CSV Data Set Configuration - see [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) guide.

Any questions - feel free to shout.

Comment: thank you for ur reply.in browser configuration after configuring am getting  error i.e proxy server refusing connections